# SQL Select data from table when date is either specified or empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select data from my database when a particular column in a table has a specific data or it is not filled.
here is my sql code:

```
SELECT
bus.bus_id,
bus.seats,
entity.entityid,
entity.company_name,
entity.logo AS companylogo,
route.start_point,
route.drop_point,
route.boarding_time,
route.arrival_time,
FROM
loading_buses
INNER JOIN bus ON loading_buses.bus_id = bus.bus_id
INNER JOIN route ON loading_buses.route_id = route.route_id
INNER JOIN entity ON bus.entity = entity.entityid AND route.entity_id = 
entity.entityid
WHERE
loading_buses.`current_date` ='23/1/2018' OR
loading_buses.`current_time` >= '00:00' AND
route.start_point = 'accra' AND
route.drop_point = 'kumasi'
ORDER BY
route.price ASC
```

And this is my output

[SQL OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmV7e.jpg)

```
1   49  1   STC assets/images/stc.png   accra   kumasi  1/17/2018 20:00 1/18/2018 00:00 20          9/18/2017   7/18/2017
2   15  1   STC assets/images/stc.png   accra   kumasi  1/17/2018 20:00 1/18/2018 00:00 20          9/18/2017   7/18/2017
3   55  1   STC assets/images/stc.png   accra   kumasi  1/17/2018 20:00 1/18/2018 00:00 20          9/18/2017   7/18/2017
```

In my database, the column current date is has certain date which must show depending on the date inserted or if no date in the column, it must show.
So in conclusion, result from the query show show only data for the specified date and null. But Query is displaying all data in the table

Comment: MySQL or sql-server ?

Comment: It is MySQL not sql-server

Comment: This query would result in an error. Ergo, this is not your query.

Comment: Also. Store dates and times as a single entity, and using a proper datetime data type.

Comment: Once you've fixed those issues, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use () to group your OR's:

```
WHERE
(loading_buses.`current_date` ='2018-01-23' OR loading_buses.`current_date`  is null)
AND
route.start_point = 'accra' AND
route.drop_point = 'kumasi'
```

Comment: i need some explanation

Comment: Not sure how can I explain it any better than I already did. I even gave you working example.

Comment: Only I can add is, depending how you store your date, you might need to change from current_date` ='2018-01-23' to current_date` ='23/01/2018'

Comment: i had the same thought but i figured it wouldn't work but it worked fine

Comment: its not how i am bringing the date, i wanted my query to fetch results just for a specific date set and null field

Comment: (loading_buses.`current_date` ='2018-01-23' OR loading_buses.`current_date`  is null) will bring all records to match '2018-01-23' and records that are NULL

Comment: likewise (loading_buses.current_date ='23/01/2018' OR loading_buses.current_date is null) will bring all records to match '23/01/2018' and records that are NULL, depending if you set up current_date as a string field or date field.

Comment: Got it, what if i want to check if field is just empty not null

Answer (score 0):

if you want check for null you should use is null

```
WHERE  loading_buses.`current_date` ='23/1/2018' OR
     loading_buses.`current_time`  is null
```

Or based  on your comment you can use

```
WHERE  loading_buses.`current_date` ='23/1/2018' AND
     loading_buses.`current_time`  is null
```

Comment: I want to check if the loading_buses.current_date has "23/1/2018" and also loading_buses.current_date is null

Comment: answer  updated with the and condition based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

current_date is used as keyword to define system date in many databases. So, please make sure It is not the case here.

`current_date` ='23/1/2018' ---  Change date value in this condition and see if it still returns all the data.

Also, comment out this condition --- loading_buses.`current_time` >= '00:00' 
as all the rows satisfy this condition.

Comment: @sskoko answer solved it, i just wanted specific data based on date in where clause and if coulmn as Null or empty